# How can I get a div to appear next to the element the mouse is hovering on top of? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, mouseover, appearance

I have a bunch of images wrapped in links such as these:

```
<a class="tipsFeatured" href="#" rel="products/p0.html"><img src="assets/img/products-shoppingview-and-registryview/horne/resized/pott-5pc-setting-pott.jpg" alt="Silver Cutlery" width="170" height="170" /></a>
            <a class="tipsFeatured" href="#" rel="products/p1.html"><img src="assets/img/products-shoppingview-and-registryview/horne/resized/Design-House-Stockholm-Cobalt_Pitcher.jpg" alt="Design House Stockholm Cobalt Pitcher" width="170" height="170" /></a>
```

I have a div with id #descText and I'd like that when the mouse is hovered over each of this links that div appears right next to the current element with different text each time. The "different text each time" part I know how to do, but I haven't been able to make the div appear next to the current hovered element I just have:

```
$('.tipsFeatured').bind('mouseover',function(){
        var $txt = $('#descText');
        $(this).next().append($txt.css('display','block'));
    });
```

Comment: Can you add a more complete set of HTML, CSS and JavaScript please? It's difficult to provide an accurate answer without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you :

```
$('.tipsFeatured').hover(
    function(){
        var element = $(this).children(),
            text    = element.attr('data');

    $(this).append('<div id="descText">'+text+'</div>');

    },
    function(){

    $('#descText').remove();

    }
);
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/hx8Tv/2/

Replace `<span>` with you images.

A little [extra](http://jsfiddle.net/hx8Tv/4/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a combination of [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) or [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) *that takes 2 functions* otherwise anything being [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)ed or [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)ed will be added on every mouse move over the anchor tag. I prefer the explicit mouseenter/leave but it's personal preference since the dual function hover is an alias for the mouseenter/leave.

The following will make the `#descText` visible and append it to the `<a>`, so that is *inside* the anchor and therefore is hyperlinked. If you do not want the `<span id="descText"/>` hyperlinked use `.after()` instead of `.append()`.

HTML

```
<a class="tipsFeatured" href="#" rel="products/p0.html"><img src="assets/img/products-shoppingview-and-registryview/horne/resized/pott-5pc-setting-pott.jpg" alt="Silver Cutlery" width="170" height="170" /></a>
<a class="tipsFeatured" href="#" rel="products/p1.html"><img src="assets/img/products-shoppingview-and-registryview/horne/resized/Design-House-Stockholm-Cobalt_Pitcher.jpg" alt="Design House Stockholm Cobalt Pitcher" width="170" height="170" /></a>

<span id="descText">the text</span>
```

CSS

```
#descText { display:none; }
```

JavaScript

```
$('.tipsFeatured').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).append($('#descText').show());
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#descText').hide();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eHmY5/2/)

I assume that you have multiple *image descriptions* though, and are somehow changing the text inside the `#descText` before appending, as this only works with one unique `#descText` element.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is that you can make an empty `<div id="foo_1"></div>` next to each element that you'd like to have feature a description hoverover and make sure each id is unique. Then in the javascript, you can say something like `$('foo_'+id)` and have it identified by the id variable.

Answer (score 0):

By using `.next()`, you are selecting the next `a` element in the DOM and appending the description div to it instead of inserting the description div after the current `a` element.

Try this:

```
$('.tipsFeatured').bind('mouseover',function(){
    var $txt = $('#descText');
    $(this).after($txt.css('display','block'));
});
```

which uses jQuery's [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) function.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't that be:

```
$('.tipsFeatured').bind('mouseover',function(){
    var $txt = $('#descText');
    $txt.css('display','block');
    $(this).after($txt);
});
```

**EDIT:**

Updated my answer, which is what I was coming back to the page to do anyway. A good lesson - better to test first, then post, than to post and correct.

Comment: Why the downvote? Here's a fsfiddle that does just that: http://jsfiddle.net/hx8Tv/

Comment: I changed line for to `$(this).after($txt);`, but otherwise, I'm interested to hear why this is wrong. I was coming back to the post to edit it anyway :). Too slow?

Comment: This does the exact same thing as the poster's original code.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$('.tipsFeatured').hover(function() {
    var contentInsideElement = /* 'Whatever'; */
    var descText =  $("#descText");
      if(descText.length)
        descText.html(contentInsideElement);
      else
         descText = $('<div id="descText">' + contentInsideElement +   '</div>').appendTo(document.body);

    $(this).after(descText);
   }, function() { // Remove new element on mouseout
     $('#descText').hide();
});
```

Comment: Did you just steal part of my answer to make your own?

Comment: @65Fbef05  - No ways, this is my own implementation. I never look at other answers and reply.

Comment: @65Fbef05  - Before you comment look at your answer and compare with mine.

Comment: That line might have be been a coincidence.

Comment: Coincidence nothing. Two identical comments with exactly the same named variables? Again, not cool dude.

Comment: Look at the implementation dude. Then you can say its copied.

Comment: If you're going to copy code, then revise it to create an answer, copy the OP's - Not from another person's answer. That's terrible etiquette.